# Name Manager Icons Not Appearing

Tags: excel, named-ranges

In named manager I am used to seeing icons in the Name Column denoting if its a table, range etc. For some reason I no longer see the icons. Any idea on what I did to turn this off?

Thanks

Name Manager Not showing icons:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the old fashioned. Close Excel, restart machine, open Excel, create a new named range trick?

Comment: @QHarr That was the first thing I did haha. I tried opening other files and closing and opening again but no luck.

Comment: What is the set-up? Excel version/bit etc?

Comment: @QHarr Version 1808 Build 10366.20016